# node.js-MySQL COUNT the number of records

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have following code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'test'
});
connection.connect();

var userdata = '24';

var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names WHERE age = ?'
connection.query(sql, [userdata], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Query result: ', rows);
});

connection.end();
```

I want to get the total number of records from table 'names' where 'age' = 24. I receive the following on my node.js command prompt.

```
Query result:  [ { 'COUNT(*)': '14' } ]
```

My question is how to store this number 14 in a variable for further use.

I know I can do this just by changing the 'sql' line to

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM names WHERE age = ?'
```

and then console line to

```
console.log('Query result: ', rows.length);
```

But still is there another way?

Comment: `rows[0]['COUNT(*)']`? You are dealing with pure SQL, so I guess you don't have other choice.

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Rewrite the

```
var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names WHERE age = ?'
```

To look like, i.e.:

```
var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS namesCount FROM names WHERE age = ?'
```

Then, you will get Query result:  `[ { 'namesCount': '14' } ].`

so now you have

```
rows[0].namesCount
```

Good enough?